# How to change system localization through AutoIt?

Tags: winapi, autoit

One of my (very old VB6) programs crashes when the system uses numbers in thousands with a "," (european?) instead of a "." (American?). This is can be changed in windows using the "format" setting (found in the localization settings).

What I want to do is build a script that changes this setting in Windows 7 during the use of the program. I know I probably have to use the Winapi extension in AutoIt, but is there a function for this so I can make a script that calls it and changes this setting and on opening and back on the closing of the program?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", "sThousand", "REG_SZ", ".")` to change this setting directly. You can find a good explanation for these values at [windowsitpro](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/jsi-tip-0311-regional-settings-registry). Maybe you want to change "*sDecimal*" as well?

Answer (score 1):

Look at _WinAPI_SetLocaleInfo() and _WinAPI_GetLocaleInfo() in WinAPILocale.au3.